# how to convert strings given by the user into a list

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
user_input=input("Enter names separated by commas  ")
```

ie user_input can now be `user_input="Kean,Peter,john"`.

I need help on how to make the `user_input` look like this `user_input=["kean","Peter","john"]`

Comment: I mean your questions has already been asked, and this is that question. Please check that question's answers, if they're helpful, please mark this question as a duplicate. See [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), you can get a list splited by a delimiter:

```
>>> user_input = "Kean,Peter,john" 
>>> user_input.split(',')
['Kean', 'Peter', 'john']
```

Comment: I have done what you have done.. but  my output is just Kean,Peter,john....not as a list

Comment: @BradleyJuma, You need to reassign to `user_input` if you want change `user_input`: `user_input = user_input.split(',')`

Comment: I didn't do it on purpose sorry about that